# Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/xxxxx LibGDX Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm making a Android game with LibGDX and I want to use the Google Play Game Services API but I can't get it working.

Here's what happens when I try to login:

```
06-12 20:08:47.745: E/Volley(4046): [253] tk.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/115171141636978128288
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046): Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046): ebw
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at dwp.a(SourceFile:146)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at dfx.a(SourceFile:390)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at dfx.a(SourceFile:371)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at dex.a(SourceFile:719)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at ecp.a(SourceFile:250)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:389)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/SignInIntentService(4046):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-12 20:08:47.846: E/LoadSelfFragment(9533): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
06-12 20:08:47.846: W/SignInActivity(9533): onSignInFailed()...
06-12 20:08:47.846: W/SignInActivity(9533): ==> Returning non-OK result: 10004
```

I checked if the app is linked and if the SHA1 key is the same between my keystore and in the Google Developers Console and I checked if I was been a tester of the app who was allowed to use the API.

Now I don't know where to look for to get this working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes I did, my API settings were mistaken.

Comment: what was the api you needed?

Comment: @Claymeuns , what solution you found? because i m having same issue right now.