# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?

Tags: android, youtube, android-volley

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure as to how to solve this.
Tried searching a lot but no progress.

This is the error

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,id&fields=nextPageToken,pageInfo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your SHA1 fingerprint, the issue may be with your SHA1 fingerprint
as stated here

[Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/xxxxx LibGDX Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191311/unexpected-response-code-403-for-https-www-googleapis-com-games-v1-players-xxx)

[Error 403 when trying to sign in to Google Game Services in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643751/error-403-when-trying-to-sign-in-to-google-game-services-in-android)

Comment: SaravInfern Thanks a lot for the help.I guess this will work for me.